# how to fix CORS error in laravel vuejs project

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cors

I am developing a project that uses Laravel and vuejs. I get an error when I try to call an online gateway URL. How do I fix the error?

The code I wrote to send the online gateway URL:

```
    @header('Location: '. $url);
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url={$url}' />";
    echo "<script>window.location.href = '{$url}';</script>";
    exit;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think, you should use barryvdh/laravel-cors package to fix it